# Finding statistically increasing and decreasing sub-sequences in a (noisy) vector

Tags: statistics, time-series, data-mining

I have a vector of real non-negative values of length ~60. The values represent a geometric property (can be area, circumference, etc.) of an object extracted from a movie of a biological sample, and each entry in the vector corresponds to a different frame within the movie.

The values can be increasing / decreasing / still, and I would like to apply a statistical algorithm that would partition / segment the vector into regions in which the values show clear statistical increase / decrease / still.

In matlab there's a function called 'findchangepts' for finding change points, and one option is to use 'linearity' (ie slope and intercept) as the statistic, but I don't know if this is a legitimate statistical procedure.

Any suggestions?

Thanks all!